# Как отсортировать колонку Yii2, если она встречается в 3-х разных таблицах?

Tags: yii2, activerecord, model

Есть колонка `serial_number`, которая находится в таблицах: `network_hardware, office_equipment, server`. Основная таблица не хранит эту колонку, а подтягивает по отношению.

**Model**

```php
@property NetworkHardware|OfficeEquipment|Server $serialNumber Серийный номер

/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getSerialNumber() {
    if ($this->equipment_type === GeneralInformationEntity::EQUIPMENT_TYPE_NETWORK_HARDWARE) {
        return $this->hasOne(NetworkHardware::class, ['general_information_id' => 'id']);
    }

    if ($this->equipment_type === GeneralInformationEntity::EQUIPMENT_TYPE_OFFICE_EQUIPMENT) {
        return $this->hasOne(OfficeEquipment::class, ['general_information_id' => 'id']);
    }

    if ($this->equipment_type === GeneralInformationEntity::EQUIPMENT_TYPE_SERVER) {
        return $this->hasOne(Server::class, ['general_information_id' => 'id']);
    }
}
```

**View**

```php
[
    'attribute' => 'serialNumber',
    'value' => function($model) {
        return $model->serialNumber->serial_number ?? '';
    }
],
```

**Схема в БД** выглядит так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как при таком раскладе сделать сортировку по столбцу `serialNumber`?

Comment: сортировка по нескольким таблицам насколько я знаю невозможна, думаю надо пересмотреть схему таблиц

Comment: @Blacknife и так и так пробовал, пришлось переделать схему. Добавил промежуточную с серийным номером. Ну странно, что нельзя в yii это сделать...

Comment: это нельзя не в yii, это нельзя в базе данных

Comment: @Blacknife хорошо, с как вытащить одну и ту же колонку с 3 таблиц как 1? С помощью union можно это сделать.

Comment: с использованием union подготовьте query по примеру https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-query-builder#union, подсуньте его в dataProvider, так должно сработать; ваш вопрос слишком прямо понял, извиняюсь если ввел в заблуждение, но если у вас не терабайты денормализованных данных в этих таблицах то лучше все-таки нормализовать схему чтобы не заниматься подобным

Comment: может я чего не так понял, но разве `order by table1.field1 ASC | DESC, table2.field2 ASC | DESC ...` делать нельзя?